# Why isn't featurec create a contradiction?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic, minikanren

This is a contradiction:

```
(run* [q]
  (== q true)
  (== q false)) 

-> ()
```

Because there can't be a q that is `true` and `false` at the same time.

Shouldn't this be a contradiction as well?

```
(run* [q]
  (featurec q {:k true})
  (featurec q {:k false}))  

-> ((_0 :- (clojure.core.logic/featurec _0 {:k true})
           (clojure.core.logic/featurec _0 {:k false})))
```

I don't know what that `:-` mean. But since map keys are unique, I suppose there cannot be a map that can have `:k` to be `true` as well as `false`. How can I make sure the second goal doesn't match?

### Another Example

```
(run* [q]
  (fresh [x]
    (featurec x {:k false})     
    (== q true)
    (featurec x {:k q}))) -> (true)
```

I am interpreting this as:

- `x` is a map-like with `:k` as `false`.
- `q` is `true`.
- `q` is the value of `:k` of `x`

### What am I trying to do exactly?

I am trying to use `featurec` to create goals like:

```
(defn is-a-foo [x v]
  (featurec x {:foo v}))

(defn is-a-bar [x v]
  (featurec x {:bar v}))
```

Then I'd like to be able to say:

```
(defn foo-implies-bar [x]
  (conde [(is-a-foo [x true]) (is-a-bar [x true])])
```

Comment: A. Webb: I missed the second term there, lighttable hides by default. I suppose I better close this one since there is actually a contradiction here.

Comment: I think it is still a good question.